# Javascript Loan Calculator

Tags: javascript

When I run the following code in Chrome, it tells me that `calculate` is not defined. The code is meant to be a loan calculator.

```
   <!--DOCTYPE html--> 
     <form name="loandata">
    <table>
        <tr><td colspan=3><h1><b>Enter Loan Information</b></h1></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1)</td>
            <td>Amount of the loan (any currency):</td>
            <td><input type=text name=principal size=12 onChange="calculate()"></td>
        </tr>
    </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2)</td>
            <td>Annual percentage rate of interest</td>
            <td><input type=text name=interest size=12 onChange="calculate()"></td>
        </tr>
    </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3)</td>
            <td>Repayment period in years:</td>
            <td><input type=text name=years size=12 onChange="calculate()"></td>
        </tr>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan=3>
        <h1><b>
            <input type=button value="Compute" onClick="calculate()">
            Payment Information
        </h1></b> 
    </td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4)</td>
        <td>Your monthly payment:</td>
        <td><input type=text name=total interest size=12></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function calculate(){
        var principal= document.loandata.principal.value; //Get the input principal amount
        var interest = document.loandata.interest.value/100/12; //Get the input interest amnount 
        var payments= document.loandata.years.value*12; //get the number of years to payback the loan
        var y =math.pow(1+ interest, payments);
        var monthly = (principal*y*interest)/(y-1);
        if(!isNaN(monthly) &&
            (monthly 1= Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY)&&
            (monthly != Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY){
                document.loandata.payment.value =round(monthly);
                    document.loandata.total.value= round(monthly*payments);
                    document.loandata.totalinterest.value=
                    round(*(monthly*payments)-principal);
                }
            }
            function round(y){
                return Math.round(y*100)/100;
            }
    </script>
```

Comment: Get the script section to the top the page.

Comment: I tried this, it didn't work :L

Comment: @Hearner: that's not a very good advice, since loading CSS/JS is blocking the HTML rendering. So best practise is to put the JS on the bottom. That way the HTML gets renderered before the JS is loaded

Comment: The positioning of the script element is irrelevant. The function does need to be defined before it is called, but it is called when the events are triggered, not when the intrinsic event attributes are parsed.

Comment: @devnull69 — You realise that you just gave a (wrong) answer in the same comment that you said people shouldn't answer "here" (which I assume meaning "in the comments")?

Answer (score 4):

> it tells me that calculate is not defined

It does, but before that it tells you:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number
```

Deal with the first error first. Errors lead to further errors.

> ```
> monthly 1= Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY)&&
> ```

You missed your shift key and typed `1` instead of `!`. That syntax error prevents the function declaration from being evaluated successfully which is why the function doesn't exist when you try to call it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of syntax errors, that is your only problem.  math.pow should be Math.pow, 1= should be !=, and you have some issues with parenthesis not matching.

```
function calculate(){
  var principal = document.loandata.principal.value; //Get the input principal amount
  var interest = document.loandata.interest.value/100/12; //Get the input interest amnount 
  var payments = document.loandata.years.value*12; //get the number of years to payback the loan
  var y = Math.pow(1+ interest, payments);
  var monthly = (principal*y*interest)/(y-1);
  if(!isNaN(monthly) && monthly !== Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY && monthly !== Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY ){
    document.loandata.payment.value = round(monthly);
    document.loandata.total.value = round(monthly*payments);
    document.loandata.totalinterest.value = round((monthly * payments) - principal);
  }
}
```

You should pickup a linter like jshint. It will help keep your syntax in check.